# Insert null in @JoinColumn field

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
(
    id                      BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS positions
(
    id                   BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_user_id       BIGINT,  -- can be null its cause without REFERENCES users (id)
    user_id              BIGINT REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

And entity class

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Position> positions;
}

@Table(name = "positions")
@Entity
public class Position {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_user_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
    private User parentUser;
}
```

Accordingly, business logic `parentUser` can be null but when I try to insert a new position get the error:

> 2022-11-21 18:24:21:934 ERROR i.n.c.impl.ErrorListenerLoggerImpl -
> exceptionOccurred, Connection: 207475, Exception:
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
> org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
> unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
> flushing : ltd.package.model.Position.parentUser ->
> ltd.package.model.User; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
> unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
> flushing : ltd.package.model.Position.parentUser ->
> ltd.package.model.User

Is it possible to insert a new Position with null as `parentUser`?

Comment: Yes - it should be possible.
Please include the part of your code where you create the entities.
Seems your issue is not an actual `null` value, but some reference that is not yet persisted, i.e. you might be missing a call to `EntityManager.save` or some cascade on create on the entity.

Comment: @Jochen Reinhardt I make just `positionRepository.save(position);` Im use Spring Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The problem is not the fact that the relationship is null.
The problem is that `parentUser` is set to an unmanaged object.

You need to show how you are creating the object `position`, but I bet somewhere, you are initializing `parentUser` and that's what's causing the exception.

You can quickly check by setting `parentUser` to null before saving the position:

```
...
position.setParentUser(null);
positionRepository.save(position);
```

Make sure that when you create a new `Position` object, you are also not initializing the `parentUser`.